# how to access reducer in validate.js for redux-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

So I want to access some data from my reducer so I can use it in my validate.js for my redux-form validation

```
const validate = (values, props) => {
  const errors = {};
     state.get('deposits').depositMethod // this is what I want to achieve
  return errors;
};

class VisaDeposit extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const {
            /* eslint-disable react/prop-types */
            handleSubmit,
            pristine,
            reset,
            submitting,
            selectedCard,
        } = this.props;

        return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div className={s.newField}>
                    <div>
                        <Field
                            id="numberOnCard"
                            label="Card number"
                            name="numberOnCard"
                            component={renderField}
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="Card number"
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button
                    type="submit"
                    disabled={pristine || submitting}
                    className={s.submit}
                    >Submit
                </button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

const selector = formValueSelector('accountDeposits');

const Form = reduxForm({
  form: 'accountDeposits',
  destroyOnUnmount: false,
  forceUnregisterOnUnmount: true,
  validate,
})(VisaDeposit);

const StyledForm = withStyles(s)(Form);

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    selectedCard: selector(state, 'selectedCard'),
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    loadRegisteredCards: bindActionCreators(loadRegisteredCards, dispatch),
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(StyledForm);
```

How can I access state so I can get data from my reducer? I tried researching the documentation and everything else but I can't seem to find a way to access state.

I tried using `this.state` but it returns a value of undefined.

Comment: `console.log(this.state.deposits.depositMethode);` What does this say?

Comment: you should use this.state not state

Comment: I tried logging this.state but it's undefined atm

Comment: So the whole `state` is undefined or just the attribute?

Comment: the whole state is undefined. updated the question a bit with code.

Comment: Could you post the whole component?

Comment: updated it @Nocebo

Comment: Probalby unrelated to your issue, but you can access this.props in your render. So you should be able to do e.g. this: `this.props.handleSubmit`

Comment: You might need to bind your function to your component. The scope of `this` might be wrong. Try to place your function within the component and access it with `this.state....`

Comment: Isn't validate supposed to be a separate function so you can place it when you call the reduxForm function like what I did? Can you share a code snippet?

Comment: Yeah you are right. Was trying to point out, that you can't access `this` or `state` if its not bound

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the `values`, like so -

```
const validate = values => {
  const errors = {};
  if (!values.numberOnCard) {
    errors.numberOnCard = 'Required';
  }
  return errors;
};
```

I would suggest to go through the [docs](http://redux-form.com/7.0.3/examples/syncValidation/)

Comment: I know how to use `validate.js` I just did not post the whole code of the file. I just posted that I want to access the reducer data inside this file.